# Selenium Chrome Web Driver Failing on Jenkins

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have setup Jenkins to connect to my GitHub repo to run a sample TestNG automated test.

my @BeforeSuite method where I call the driver is as follows:

```
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeSuite
public void initDriver() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("You are testing in Chrome");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

}
```

The tests run on the first build if I create a new Free Style project. They also run if I make an incorrect change the @BeforeMethod in the repo and then correct the mistake and run the build again. However, if I try to run another build after a successful build I get the following from the console log:

```
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with:             org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@cf768c
You are testing in Chrome
Configuring TestNG with:     org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@f2b07d
Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.342 sec     <<< FAILURE!
initDriver(Patrick.Patrick.TestNGSeleniumSimpleSearchExample)  Time elapsed:     0.288 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be     set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see     http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be     downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
    at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:110)
    at     org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:291)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
    at     Patrick.Patrick.TestNGSeleniumSimpleSearchExample.initDriver(TestNGSeleniumSimpl    eSearchExample.java:22)


Results :

Failed tests:       initDriver(Patrick.Patrick.TestNGSeleniumSimpleSearchExample): The path to the     driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;     for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.     The latest version can be downloaded from     http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

It is telling me that the driver executable must be set by the "webdriver.chrome.driver" yet my code is correct and it runs initially but after a second build it does not run due to above error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this also happen locally or only when run in a Jenkins build? What command are you using to trigger your tests? Does "You are testing in Chrome" get called on the 2nd build? If not, is there anywhere else in your code that might create a `ChromeDriver`?

Comment: Hi @mrfreester . No this does not happen locally . I have the same code on eclipse and i can run it as a "TestNG" test multiple times over and no issues. I'm running it as invoke top level maven with goals set to "test" on Jenkins. Yes even when it fails it declares that it is running chrome so it seems to be failing on the system.setProperty line. That is the only method creating the driver. The code is the exact same from the sucessful build, to get another successful build i must either create a new job or else change the code, run a failed build, change code back and run again. Thanks

Comment: I assume that you execute your tests with the maven sureFire plugin. Then you can try the following things: set reuseForks to false, try to set the webdriver.chrome.driver over the argLine. Here is the official doc: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html